# Load all items from a list of string, launching minecraft with libraries listed in the files list

Tags: java, vb.net, process, minecraft

I'm making a launcher, this launcher using process with java, my problem is, I have a list(of string) called "files", I want to build the process with `-cp` all items from this unknow count list. I want to launch minecraft, in the "files", my launcher stored the libraries.

**With more code details:**
**MainClass: The minecraft's main class**,
**JavaPath: The java location in the computer**,
**MaxMemAlloc: The maximal heap size for java**,
**MinMemAlloc: The minimal heap size for java**,
**Version: The minecraft version**

My code looks like this:

```
Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = Javapath
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -Xms" + MinMemAlloc + "M -Xmx" + MaxMemAlloc + "M " +
    "-Djava.library.path=" + Root + String.Format("\versions\{0}\{0}-natives", Version) +
    " -cp " +
    String.Join(";", Files) +
    Root + String.Format("\versions\{0}\{0}.jar ", Version) + MainClass +
    " --username=" + Username +
    " --version " + Version +
    " --gameDir " + Root +
    " --assetsDir " + Root + "\assets" +
    " --assetIndex " + AssetIndex +
    " --accessToken null" +
    " --userProperties {}" +
    " --userType mojang" +
    " --uuid (Default)"
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Root
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
Application.DoEvents()
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Main.p_OutputDataReceived
AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Main.p_OutputDataReceived
p.Start()
```

How to scroll and `-cp` all items from the "files", and launch the process? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join.aspx) method to easily get a delimiter-separated string from a list.

```
" -cp " +
String.Join(";", Files) + ' other stuff
```

E.g. if your list has `asdf` and `qwer`, it will output `asdf;qwer`.

Comment: Thanks, but this not working, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/KqPPPK1x, I tested with minecraft 1.5.2, and minecraft 1.8.1. Any idea?

Comment: @Programmer2011 Without more information on the command you ran and the environment you ran it in, it's impossible to answer. Ask a new question or edit your question to ask that.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem with your code, the problem: to use string.join method, I need to add versions into the files, then use your method, Thanks!